# How to add specific directory for a file during tar file generation?

Tags: tar

When I create a `.tar` file using the `tar` command, what option do I need to use to add a specific directory hierarchy to the file?

For example:

```
Test_File.tar
    |__   MAIN
            |__ SUB1
                   |__ Process.txt
```

Comment: Where is the `Process.txt` file located relative to the current directory?

Answer (score 1):

From the top of the manual:

```
Examples:
  tar -cf archive.tar foo bar  # Create archive.tar from files foo and bar.
```

Therefore:
`tar cf tarfile.tar directory-to-tar`

---

Note:
In Unix speak a directory is a file, and many other things also: If it is in a directory, then it has a file-name, and it is a file.